# Number of roots of polynomial over modulus $p$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> Any polynomial with $d$ roots over arithmetic modulo a prime $p$ has degree at most $d$.
>
> **Answer:** False. $x^2 + 2x + 3 \pmod{5}$ has no roots and has degree $2$.

I know that there is no clear factorization to find the roots of this polynomial but why does the answer say it has $0$ roots. Can't we still use quadratic formula to come up with $2$ roots?

Comment: It sounds like you should try to use the quadratic formula and see what happens.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note:  that quadratic polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb R$ either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 1: Exhaustive search for roots.

Since there are only $p=5$ residues modulo $5$, we can directly evaluate the polynomial at each possible $x$:
\begin{array}{c|c}
x & x^2 + 2x + 3 \\
\hline 
0 & 3 \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 \\ 
3 & 3 \\ 
4 & 2
\end{array}

None of these values are $0$, so the polynomial has no roots in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_5$.

### Method 2: Complete the square.

We can complete the square in $x$:
$$
x^2 + 2x + 3 = (x^2 + 2x + 1) + 2 = (x + 1)^2 + 2. 
$$
Thus, a root $x$ would be a solution to the equation
$$
(x + 1)^2 + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}, 
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
(x + 1)^2 \equiv -2 \pmod{5}, 
$$
or since $-2 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$,
$$
(x + 1)^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}. 
$$

Here's the problem, though: $3$ is not a perfect square modulo $5$. There are [sophisticated ways](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Quadratic_reciprocity) to verify this, but since $p = 5$ is not very big, we can just check all $5$ residues:
\begin{array}{c|c}
u & u^2 \\
\hline 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 4 \\ 
3 & 4 \\ 
4 & 1
\end{array}

Notice that none of the squares are congruent to $3$ modulo $5$, hence the equation cannot be solved.

### Method 3: Quadratic formula.

The discriminant of the quadratic polynomial is
$$
\Delta = (2)^2 - 4(1)(3) \equiv 2 \pmod{3}. 
$$
Since the roots of the polynomial, according to the quadratic formula, involves the square root of this discriminant, i.e.
$$
x = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{2}}{2}, 
$$
solutions will only exist if we can find such a square root, i.e., there is some residue $u$ modulo $5$ such that $u^2 = 2$. Again, by the table in Method 2, no such residue exists.

---

No matter how you argue, the conclusion is the same: the polynomial has no roots over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Answer (score 1):

If roots existed their sum would be $-2\equiv 3$ and their product $3$ (by $x^2-sx+p=0$).

The only couples possibles for the sum are $(0,3),(1,2)$ and $(4,4)$ of sum $8\equiv 3$, but none of them gives a product of $3$.